# Why do we use distributed cache in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, reduce, distributed-cache

There is a lot of file transfer across nodes in map reduce framework anyway.
Then how does the use of distributed cache improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

DistributedCache is a facility provided by the Map-Reduce framework to cache files needed by applications. Once you cache a file for your job, hadoop framework will make it available on each and every data nodes (in file system, not in memory) where you map/reduce tasks are running. The files are transferred via the network, usually via HDFS. It will cause no more strain on the network than using HDFS for anything that's a non data local task.

Comment: Thanks , So you are saying , transfer of data over network is already an overhead . But accessing a data which is remote or non local , have more effects on performance ?

Comment: Explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061187/distributed-cache-and-performance-hadoop

Comment: Note that data is transferred from local disk to hdfs before hand. it doesn't count towards the performance as the program is not started. After that your map reduce program starts, and it runs (or try to) where the data is, it doesn't  bring the data to program. But output from map task do get transferred to reducer and combiner can be used to reduce amount of that.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is not whole lot of file transfer while the program is running. Idea is to minimize network data transfer. That's the reason computation is moved  close to data.
2. Distributed cache is the data which is required by all map or reduce tasks not like normal data where only part of that data (task split) is required. Thats why its distributed to all the nodes which runs the tasks.